# How to find the equation of the plane through two points and parallel to the line

Tags: linear-algebra, plane-geometry

> How to find the equation of the plane through points $(2, -1, 0)$ and $ (3, 4, 5)$ and parallel to the line  $2x=3y=4z$.

If i find out the direction ratios:
$$a : b : c = (3-2) : (4+1) : (5-0) = 1 : 5 : 5$$

As we know general form of a plane is $ax + by + cy + d = 0$

Now how to go forward?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I have edited the question.

Comment: You can use the 2 given points to create two equations. Also, the normal vector of the plane, i.e. $(a,b,c)$, should be perpendicular to the given line (i.e. have zero dot product). That gives one more equation. Now, you have 3 equation for the 4 unknowns $(a,b,c,d)$. As you can see the problem won't always have a solution. This happens when the given line and the line created by the two given points intersect or they are skew and not perpendicular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use following formula which is for equation of a plane passing through a given straight line($l_1)$ and parallel to another given line $(l_2)$:

${\begin{vmatrix}x-x_1&y-y_1&z-z_1\\l_1&m_1&n_1\\l_2&m_2&n_2\end{vmatrix}}=0$

Let line $l_1$   passing through the given points (2, -1, 0) and (3, 4, 5) be:

$\frac {x-2}1=\frac{y+1}5=\frac z5\Rightarrow l_1=1, m_1=5, n_1=5$

and line $l_2$ be:

$2x=3y=4z\rightarrow \frac x{\frac12}=\frac y{\frac13}=\frac z{\frac14}\Rightarrow l_2=\frac 12, m_2=\frac 13, n_2=\frac 14$

Now plugging  values in formula we obtain:

$(x-2)\begin{vmatrix}5&5\\\frac13&\frac14\end{vmatrix}+(y+1)\begin{vmatrix}5&1\\\frac14&\frac12\end{vmatrix}+(z)\begin{vmatrix}1&5\\\frac12&\frac13\end{vmatrix}=0$

Now calculate determinants and find the required equation.